# I only want to keep the row in a dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
zip_count[zip_count.Zipcode.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
zip_count

    Zipcode Employees
0   00728   1
1   00926   1
2   01027   2
3   01028   4
4   01040   2
... ... ...
652 98121   1
653 98144   1
654 98296   1
655 B1S 3   1
656 POSTAL  2
```

I only want to keep the zipcode start with "02---", how should I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
zip_count.loc[zip_count['Zipcode'].str.startswith('02')]
```